# Google Reseller API to know if a CustomerId (domain) is my reseller customer

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-reseller-api

I have an app, through which Google G Suite customers can transfer their billing to my reseller console. Now if someone tries to transfer a domain which is already under my account, how can I identify that and return a corresponding message.

I am using PHP as my development language

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is straight forward API call or not for this purpose but following endpoint can be used to get this information.

> GET
>   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/reference/customers/domain

The response format if customer is already under reseller account

```
{
  "kind": "reseller#customer",
  "customerId": string,
  "customerDomain": string,
  "postalAddress": {
    "kind": "customers#address",
    "contactName": string,
    "organizationName": string,
    "locality": string,
    "region": string,
    "postalCode": string,
    "countryCode": string,
    "addressLine1": string,
    "addressLine2": string,
    "addressLine3": string
  },
  "phoneNumber": string,
  "alternateEmail": string,
  "resourceUiUrl": string,
  "customerDomainVerified": boolean
}
```

Otherwise if domain exists but customer is not under reseller account,

```
{
  "kind": "reseller#customer",
  "customerId": string,
  "customerDomain": string
}
```

If the domain itself doesn't have google apps account, an error status will be returned.

You can check on any of the difference in JSON response to find if user already exists under reseller account or not.